# JavaScript Regexp - allowing carriage return lets other unwanted characters validate

Tags: javascript, regex, carriage-return

I have a textarea in which i want to allow only a-z 0-9 \s .,- and \r \n

I'm using a JQuery 3rd party plugin. This is what i have for validation rules:

```
        jQuery("#description").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[a-z0-9 ,.-]*$/gi)) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Only: a-z 0-9 period comma dash space"
    });
```

Which works fine for a-z 0-9 ,.-

However, when i add \r within those sq.brackets it allows enter to validate which doesnt throw the message up, but the user can input *any* character they want and it validates.  The messages show, if needed, when focus has left the textarea.

I have also added the 'm' flag for multi line and not added the \r which gave me the same effect.

Been scratching my head on this for a week, have only just started learning regexp. Does anyone have an idea which direction i should be looking in order to solve this please?

Comment: How does your regex pattern look when you have the \r in it?

Comment: expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[a-z0-9 ,.-\r]*$/gi))

Comment: Okay . . . I think I know your issue . . . adding answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = "This is a\ntest";

string.match(/^[a-z\s]$/i); // ["This is a\ntest" ]
string.match(/^[a-z \r\n]+$/i); // ["This is a\ntest" ]
```

You don't even need `m` apparently. Maybe you need to double escape your escape characters? It looks like there might be some processing going on there. So:

```
string.match(/^[a-z \\r\\n]+$/i);
```

Keep in mind that `\s` contains space, newline, carriage return and tab (`\t`)

Comment: It was a processing issue. I include the js file from within a php script. I hadnt thought they would need escaping as its just a file being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is around the "-" character.  Within a character set ("[xyx]"), the dash is one of the few special characters.  When it comes in between two characters, it sets a range.  When it has a character only on one side, it is treated simply as a dash character.

In your first regex, you end with the dash (`/^[a-z0-9 ,.-]*$/gi`), so it treats it as a dash character.

In your second one (`/^[a-z0-9 ,.-\r]*$/gi`), you end with the \r, creating a little sub-range of `.-\r`

You should be able to fix this by either moving the dash to the end (or beginning) of the set, or escaping it:

`/^[a-z0-9 ,.\r-]*$/gi`

. . . or . . .

`/^[a-z0-9 ,.\-\r]*$/gi`